# TypeError: _this.props.onSave is not a function

Tags: reactjs, typescript, debugging, react-router, next.js

I am trying to build a simple blog app using **Nextjs(React+Typescript)** and I am getting this error

> TypeError: _this.props.onSave is not a function

How can I resolve this error? 
I have already asked a query on stackoverflow about this but so far no luck. This is the link:
[this.props.onSave is not a function- Uncaught typescript error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60287892/this-props-onsave-is-not-a-function-uncaught-typescript-error?noredirect=1#comment106643502_60287892)

I have tried everything from binding to literally debugging lines. How can I resolve this error?

Answer (score 0):

That error is basically saying, you did not pass prop `onSave` onto that component, or you did pass it, but somehow incorrectly.

I advise, use `console.log(this.props)` or `console.log(this.props.onSave)`  to find out what you did really pass.

Also, pay attention to this, just make sure, you are passing a function, not it's return value

```
class Parent extends Component {

    myCustomMethod() {
        console.log("call me ");
    }

    render() {

        //incorrect
        //return <MyCustomComponent callback={this.myCustomMethod()} />;

        //this one is correct, without parentheses
        return <MyCustomComponent callback={this.myCustomMethod} />;
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried console.log on both handleSave and onSave. The output of handleSave is object Object and the output of onSave is undefined. I ain't understanding how can I resolve this, I have uploaded my code in the stackoverflow link above. The same code is working normally using React+Typescript but not using Nextjs(React) with Typescript

Comment: @Rebel if it is `undefined`, ten you are not passing the prop properly

Comment: What changes could I make to get this running? onSave is undefined because I am filling a normal form and clicking on the submit button. What is the solution to this? I am new to NextJs

Comment: @Rebel a solution is simple. you need to pass a prop named "onSave" on the component where you are calling it

Comment: I have done exactly that:
<Route
                        exact
                        path="/new"
                        component={(props) => <NewQuestion {...props} onSave={this.handleSave} />} />

Answer (score 0):

Just ran into this. I was passing in the function from a parent component to the child component with an incorrect name.